# Git pull without password

Tags: git, ssh

I've been trying to figure out how to git pull using SSH, all the articles are addressing how to set up SSH keys. I have set up the keys in the same way as I do for other SSH setup situations including registering them on github, but still, I'm asked for username/pw after running:

```
git -C folder/folder/ pull --no-edit
```

on the Ubuntu server.

Comment: make sure your remotes are using the git ssh protocol instead of https?

Answer (score 0):

Your repository has what is called a "remote" that is associated with a URL. By default, `git clone` creates a remote named `origin` with the URL that you specify. This URL includes the protocol to use which is most likley HTTPS instead of SSH. You can view the remotes of your repo with `git remote -v`. You can set the URL for the remote with `git remote set-url`. For more details, type `git help remote`.